# iTunes - access to music and apps per country

Tags: itunes, applications, ios-appstore

Does access to iTunes from a particular country, mean that iPhone apps are also accessable in that country?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about what you are trying to do and what you've tried to solve your problem? For a question to be useful to others it needs to define a problem in specific terms. Could you edit or comment so we can make this into something usable by others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Access to the iTunes music store using one Apple-ID means that you can also use its apps section. The ID is connected to a credit card, and the ID gives access to the store in the country to which that credit card belongs. Gift cards have been a trick in the past to work around that.